# iOS - Adding items to plist

Tags: ios, xml, plist

I'm writing a plist from an 'NSMutableDictionary'. That works ok.

But when I want to add to the file, the new entry overrides the first entry.

What I'd like is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<names>
<name1>
    <key>
        firstname
    </key>
    <value>
        mememememe
    </value>
    <key>
        lastname
    </key>
    <value>
        mememememe
    </value>

</name1>
<name2>
    <key>
        firstname
    </key>
    <value>
        mememememe
    </value>
    <key>
        lastname
    </key>
    <value>
        mememememe
    </value>

    </name2>
</names>
Here's my code so far:



    NSString *filename = [documents stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"faves.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *loadedMiscDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filename];

 NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documents = [directories firstObject];

    NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [tempDict setValue:firstNameString forKey:@"firstname"];
    [tempDict setValue:secondNameString forKey:@"secondName"];

  [loadedMiscDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:tempDict];
    [loadedMiscDictionary writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. TIA

UPDATE

I changed my code snippet above..

Comment: have you used my answer

Comment: No, the answer is not yet complete.

Comment: means what you want to say Im not getting your problem. is it need for some code for that or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use right click + Add row for top category and for subcategories use + sign to add new one in plist file

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I need this to be a dynamic plist.

Comment: If i got it right, if your keys are same then it will overrides. You need to have different keys for every object.

Comment: To improve your code more. 1. For the first time as there may be possibility no data/plist file is there, check for it by checking dictionary count ([loadedMiscDictionary count] == 0) if true then add your app dictionary data directly to file. 2.if false then use [loadedMiscDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:tempDict]; to add new entries and [loadedMiscDictionary setDictionary:tempDict]; for updating old once.

Comment: Welcome. Hope you got the solution

Answer (score 1):

Your code overrides the old entries of the plist. You are not getting plist file entries in dictionary. Just create a new dictionary add some new entries and override old file.

- fetch plist file data
- stored it in NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray
- Add new entries in that dict. or array
- At the last get current file location and stored that newly created dict. or array which carry old and new entries in it.

I hope it will helps you